# Is there a way to extract the current frame from a plotly figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Basically, I have a plotly animation which uses a slider and pause/play buttons to go through a dataset. I want to extract the number of the current frame (i.e., the current index in the ‘steps’/‘frames’ lists which the slider is on) in a Dash callback, so that I can update a table based on the main graph.

For example, in this situation:

[Dash app with slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fPjG.png)

I would like to be able to get ‘6’, the current step number, from the figure.

Here is some example code with a toy dataset, but the same basic UI and structure (from above, minus the buttons to reduce length of code block):

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# Dataset
x = [10, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [10, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)), columns = ['x', 'y'])

# Adding a trace
trace = go.Scatter(x=df.x[0:2], y=df.y[0:2],
                            name='Location',
                            mode='markers',
                            marker=dict(color="white", 
                                        size=10,
                                        line=dict(
                                        color='DarkSlateGrey',
                                        width=2)
                                       )
                            )

# Adding frames
frames = [dict(name=k,data= [dict(type='scatter',
                           x=df.x[k:k + 1],
                           y=df.y[k:k + 1],
                            ),
                        ],
               traces = [0], 
              ) for k  in  range(len(df) - 1)] 

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], frames=frames)

# Adding a slider
sliders = [{
        'yanchor': 'top',
        'xanchor': 'left', 
        'active': 1,
        'currentvalue': {'font': {'size': 16}, 'prefix': 'Steps: ', 'visible': True, 'xanchor': 'right'},
        'transition': {'duration': 200, 'easing': 'linear'},
        'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50}, 
        'len': 0.9, 'x': 0.15, 'y': 0, 
        'steps': [{'args': [[k], {'frame': {'duration': 200, 'easing': 'linear', 'redraw': False},
                                    'transition': {'duration': 0, 'easing': 'linear'}}], 
                    'label': k, 'method': 'animate'} for k in range(len(df) - 1)       
                ]}]

fig['layout'].update(sliders=sliders)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
                    html.Div([
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id= 'my-graph',
                            figure=fig
                        ),
                        html.Br(),
                        html.Div(id='my-output'),
                    ])
            ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure')
)

# How to get the current frame index here?
def update_output_div(figure):
    return 'Output: {}'.format(figure['layout']['sliders'][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Basically, in that callback, I just want to get the current index of the slider, i.e. the current frame that the animation is on. It's displayed by the ‘Steps’ tag above the slider, so it clearly exists somewhere, but I can’t find it for the life of me (tried going through the Github source code, but couldn’t locate it).

I would really appreciate any help with this! My dataset is fairly large (20 mb) and doesn’t fit into browser memory, so I haven’t had much luck with a Dash solution using dcc.Slider and dcc.Graph that is still performant.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I think the frame number is the variable 'k' shown in the step.

Comment: Hi! You're right, but what I'm trying to do is get its current value from the figure dict, which I haven't been able to figure out. Basically, I want to find out what index k is at as it iterates through the loop. Maybe I'll give another go searching for it, but it seems like it might just be inaccessible after it's set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- https://community.plotly.com/t/trigger-callback-on-animation-frame-change/46049 there is no way to trigger a callback on a frame change
- have switched to using **dash** slider and button
- now animation can be controlled with callbacks and with `setFrame()` callback acting on a frame change from the slider
- have included **plotly** button and slider as commented out code for reference

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

# construct a figure with frames
frames=[go.Frame(name=n, data=go.Scatter(y=np.random.uniform(1, 5, 50)))
        for n in range(8)]
fig = go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames)
# fig = fig.update_layout(
#     updatemenus=[{"buttons": [{"args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": True}}],
#                                "label": "&#9654;",
#                                "method": "animate",},],
#                   "type": "buttons",}],
#     sliders=[{"steps": [{"args": [[f.name],{"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True}, "mode": "immediate",},],
#                          "label": f.name, "method": "animate",}
#                         for f in frames],
#              }],)


# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig), 
     html.Button("Play", id="dashPlay", n_clicks=0),
     dcc.Slider(id="dashSlider", min=0, max=len(frames)-1, value=0, marks={i:{"label":str(i)} for i in range(len(frames))}),
     dcc.Interval(id="animateInterval", interval=400, n_intervals=0, disabled=True),
     html.Div(id="whichframe", children=[]),
    ],
)

# core update of figure on change of dash slider    
@app.callback(
    Output("whichframe", "children"),
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("dashSlider", "value"),
)
def setFrame(frame):
    if frame:
        tfig = go.Figure(fig.frames[frame].data, frames=fig.frames, layout=fig.layout)
        try:
            tfig.layout['sliders'][0]['active'] = frame
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return frame, tfig
    else:
        return 0, fig

# start / stop Interval to move through frames
@app.callback(
    Output("animateInterval","disabled"),
    Input("dashPlay", "n_clicks"),
    State("animateInterval","disabled"),
)
def play(n_clicks, disabled):
    return not disabled
    
@app.callback(
    Output("dashSlider", "value"),
    Input("animateInterval", "n_intervals"),
    State("dashSlider", "value")
)
def doAnimate(i, frame):
    if frame < (len(frames)-1): 
        frame += 1
    else:
        frame = 0
    return frame

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful pseudocode, and a very clear explanation. That's a shame about the lack of Plotly callbacks! On a related note, do you have any strategies for making the animation via callbacks smoother, i.e. smoothly transitioning from one frame to the next, like you can do with Plotly? I tried making a basic version of this structure to test it out, and noticed that the animation was a lot jerkier.

Comment: Also, I don't have the reputation to upvote you but otherwise I definitely would, very much appreciate the help!

E: Also, this is a much nicer way of setting this up than I've seen previously; using the frames like that makes a ton of sense.

Comment: it's not pseudocode,  it's actual code that works :-). I actually don't like this line of code `tfig = go.Figure(fig.frames[frame].data, frames=fig.frames, layout=fig.layout)`. creating a new **figure** is expensive.  I couldn't find a way with `update_traces()` or `update_layout()`

Comment: you can accept the answer...  I've answered a number of questions on plotly, I'm of the opinion plotly documentation is very good,  however code examples are language independent for python, javascript and R.  Hence do not really utilise python language features

Comment: Forgot how to accept answers, whoops! Thank you, this really was a great example. I'll keep in mind that creating a figure is expensive, and see if I can come up with a version with update_traces/layout. Hopefully it will still be performant enough either way. The plotly documentation really is very solid, but I also find that community examples like the one you just shared tend to help me the most!